# Net framework 4.6.2 developer pack

Tags: .net-4.6.2

I have created wcf service with .net framework 4.6.2 developer pack in visual studio 2017 on win 10.
while deploying using exe to client pc which is having .net framework 4.6.2 sdk only giving problem .
in windows log , its showing that 4.6.2 devloper pack is not installed.

how can i acheive this.